# mi codigo no reacciona al evento 'change' de mi input

Tags: javascript, input

el addEventListener change de mi input de tipo file nunca se activa.

```
const button = dropArea.querySelector("button");
const input = dropArea.querySelector("#input-file");
let files;

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    input.click(); /* abrir el explorador de archivos */
});

input.addEventListener("change", (e) => { /* cuando se carga un archivo usando el boton*/
    files = input.files;
    dropArea.classList.add("active");
    showFiles(files);
    dropArea.classList.remove("active");
});
```

el código lo copie tal cual del tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWFwYLUGWrc minuto 36:58 en este tutorial funciona correctamente. me di cuenta que cuando se acciona el evento "click" la pagina se recarga no se si tendrá algo que ver

Comment: Hola Sebastian, es recomendable poner tu código de manera reproducible o sea completo con html y css para poder entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Tu código funciona bien con un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), tal como he puesto aqui:  https://jsfiddle.net/hrav2sy0/   Compruebalo tu mismo. Lo que quizas te confunde es que despues del showFiles la clase vuelve a borrarse y no parece quese haya hecho nada. En mi ejemplo veras que cambiar el color del background y luego da un error porque no tengo esa funcion showFiles definida, pero eso indica que ha entrado bien en el change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo solucione, el problema era que el evento "click".
lo cambie por un evento "mousedown" y la pagina ya no se recarga y funciona correctamente. quedaria asi:

```
button.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    input.click();
});
```

gracias a los que respondieron de todas formas, y perdón por explicarme tan mal en la pregunta y no agregar todo el código necesario

Answer (score 0):

Tengo conocimiento de que cuando quieres agregar una clase a un elemento a  través de  classList.add() debes colocar el nombre de la clase iniciando con un punto (.)

```
dropArea.classList.add(.active)
```

Prueba con eso y me avisas que tal te va.